# Is there a Razor View engine equivalent in flutter?

Tags: razor, flutter

I building an app that requires HTML with webview in certain page (e.g detail page) using Flutter. I am coming from Xamarin background, in Xamarin there is [Razor Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/razor-html-templates/) which basically is to create HTML combined with C#.

I've tried looking everywhere (at least) but couldn't find any, what I found is to create HTML using dart entirely.

Razor View example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So is there a Razor View engine Xamarin equivalent in Flutter?

Comment: If you need Razor, Why you wasting time with #flutter, You can better use web assembly and build the code in blazor and use webview. It will better work and you have more control on it since it's html and C#

Comment: Removing the xamarin tag as this question has nothing to do with xamarin

Comment: Maybe I am not explain it clear about the question, I mean I need html in certain page (e.g detail page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the equivalent for Razor template, there is a [Reflected Mustache](https://pub.dev/packages/reflected_mustache) package, it uses [Reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable)